# Problem with background-image hover effect - zoom out doesn't work for the right edge

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, background-image

could you please maybe take a look into this?

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="obrazek"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(218, 124, 124);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.obrazek {
  display: flex;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1667857399206-dc6d15189adc?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-out, right 0.3s ease-out, bottom 0.3s ease-out,
    left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.obrazek:hover {
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
```

Codepen:
[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/msobieraj97/pen/XWBgeam)

I want this picture to be smaller on hover. It is working but only for top, bottom and left but the right side is staying the same (I mean it doesn't change its position on hover on the right edge).

Do you have maybe any idea how to fix this and what I did wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(218, 124, 124);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.obrazek {
  display: flex;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1667857399206-dc6d15189adc?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.obrazek:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(0.94, 0.9); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.94, 0.9); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(0.94, 0.9); 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="obrazek"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work - the right edge is still on the same place as of the picture is zooming out only from top, left and bottom) + the picture is zooming out disproportionately :(

Comment: Please expand the code snippet to full page. It is zooming out from all sides. + if you want the zooming out to be proportionate, replace the transform properties like this:  
 transform: scale(0.9);

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have corrected this property transform: scale but unfortunately zooming out still doesn't work for the right corner. It works indeed on your snippet but when I copy the same code to VSC and open in Chrome there is still the same problem. Do you maybe have any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Check whether the zoom property is applied on the element using dev tools, maybe something else is overriding the property.